# update data in database succes but null

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin

i have a kotlin file to update data like this

```
fun editCustomer() {
    val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(activity)
    progressDialog.setMessage("Saving...")
    progressDialog.show()
    android.os.Handler().postDelayed({
        val editSwitch = EditSwitch()

        val custID = activity.intent.getStringExtra(ID_CUSTOMER_PROSPECT)

        editSwitch.id = custID
        editSwitch.assignedTo = "hehehehe"
        editSwitch.salesmanId = "hehehehe"

        API.getEditCustomerProspect(custID).enqueue(object : Callback<EditSwitch> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<EditSwitch>, response: Response<EditSwitch>) {
                Log.i("bebet", "onResponse: " + response.body()!!.id)
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<EditSwitch>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })

        progressDialog.dismiss()
        activity.finish()
    }, 2000)

}
```

and i have a webservice using node js like this

```
this.put = function(req,res,next) {
var id = req.query.id;
var assigned_to = req.body.assigned_to;
var salesman_id = req.body.salesman_id;
var modified_at = new Date();

connection.acquire(function(err,con,result,fields){
   if (err) throw err;
     con.query('UPDATE customer_prospect SET salesman_id = ?, assigned_to = ?, modified = ? WHERE id = "'+id+'"', [assigned_to, assigned_to, modified_at], function(err,results,fields){
       con.release();
      connection.acquire(function(err,con){
        con.query('SELECT * FROM customer_prospect where id = "'+id+'" ',[id], function(err,results,fields){
            con.release();
            res.json(results[0]);

        })
      })
   });
});

};
```

when i try check my query using postman is successfully update, but when I update in android is shown success but the data in database become null, what should i do?

Comment: This is your update service right?
and you pass only custId in it like "getEditCustomerProspect(custID)"
not all which you want to update

Comment: thank you sir its solved :) @VijayMakwana